# Get Original Source code of the URL in Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a browser control embeded in a C# windows app. I want to grab the original HTML that the url contained (not the one rendered, which could have been modified by javascript) - same as what would be in view source code in IE.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WebBrowser.DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) or [WebBrowser.DocumentStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx)

Comment: thank you. What abt the case I want to get the source of a child object - like say the url of script src in the html?

Comment: the problem with that project is that it is parser, but not based on the webbrowser... i need to grab what is on the webbrowser control